# Sleep Timer Button for a streaming player AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, timer, air

I am doing Android app using Flash CS6 and Adobe AIR. It is a  simple streaming radio player with one button for play and stop. I would like to add a new button with a timer function (sleep) that stops the player or exit the app) after 30 minutes. How could I add this?

Here is the code I am using (works fine):

```
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound);
var fl_SC:SoundChannel;
var fl_ToPlay:Boolean = true;
function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToPlay)
    {
        var s = new Sound(new URLRequest("http://myradio.com/stream.mp3"));
        fl_SC = s.play();
    }
    else
    {
        fl_SC.stop();
    }
    fl_ToPlay = !fl_ToPlay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another button for this.
2. Initialize a timer variable default as 0
3. Add event listeners to your new button for "CLICK" event and "ENTER_FRAME" event both.
4. Use your timed button's "CLICK" event for setting your timer variable's value to 30 minutes(depends on your framerate) & adding your button "ENTER_FRAME" event listener.
5. Use your timed button's "ENTER_FRAME" event to countdown your timer variable & check for is it "less than 0" & then run your sleep function & remove event listener "ENTER_FRAME"
6. I don't want to give you any code, that's not lookin fair for a question easy like that, check for tutorials, you can find lots of ways to solve something like that...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I´ve tried following your instructions with no success. Reading some tutorials and following Flash CS6 help I can't find a solution. I'm new to ActionScript

Comment: nice, i can help you if you've tried and you're "stuck". so, you can update your orginal post with current code & new problem.

Comment: Hello again, I am lost when I am at step 4:                       var fl_TimerInstance:Timer = new Timer  ;

boton15.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_TimerHandler);

boton15.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ENTER_FRAME, fl_TimerHandler);
Thank you very much!

Comment: actually, i'ven't used any timer instances before, but i'm sure it's better for your situation. But i don't know how to use it yet. I haven't tried before. So, if you wish, you can use a "Number" variable instead of "Timer" variable to solve your problem with my ways for now. you don't need ENTER_FRAME stuff if you'll use a Timer. So, i can't help you if you're going to use a Timer. But! Using a timer is the best solution for your situation! Don't forget that. So, still you wanna contunie with my ways? Or you wanna learn timer thing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I've linked the button to a new frame with the following code:

```
var s = new Sound(new URLRequest("http://myradio.com/stream.mp3"));

fl_SC = s.play();

var fl_TimerInstance_2:Timer = new Timer(900000, 1);

fl_TimerInstance_2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fl_TimerHandler_2);

fl_TimerInstance_2.start();

var fl_SecondsElapsed_2:Number = 1;

function fl_TimerHandler_2(event:TimerEvent):void
{
fl_SC.stop();
}
```

It works perfect.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards